# How to get woocommerce integration instance?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I wrote WC plugin (Integration). I want to create in my plugin a file with the following content:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');
$WC_Some_Integration->simple_redirect($_POST);
```

And send POST requests to this file. But I don't know, how I can get instance of my integration, in other words, I don't know what I must will wrote instead `WC_Some_Integration` (what to assign to this variable).

Tell me, pls, how do I do the above? Or is it the only way out to use static methods (functions)? It does not suit me too much.

Comment: Is this for AJAX? The correct way to handle AJAX in WordPress is to send request to the admin-ajax.php file, and hook your code into it. Read more [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

Comment: @JacobPeattie I know about, thx, but this is for `action` attrribute in the `<form></form>`.

Comment: You can just POST to the homepage, and then add a hook to [`template_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/). In your callback, check the `$_POST` variable for your form's field. If it exists, do your thing, otherwise do nothing.

Comment: @JacobPeattie sorry man, but I'm not interested in all the options for processing requests from forms or anythere else. I'm wondering how I can get a instance of the integration object.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the integration instance using the `integrations` object from the global `WooCommerce` object:

```
WC()->integrations->integrations['id-of-the-integration']
```

where `'id-of-the-integration'` is the [`$id`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Settings-API.html#property_id) field of the integration class, like '[maxmind_geolocation](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-integrations-maxmind-geolocation-class-wc-integration-maxmind-geolocation.html)'.

With [`WC()`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WooCommerce.html) you can get most collections of instances attached to WooCommerce.